# Proof of Convergence in Distribution for random variables with infinite variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-functions

We are asked to prove that given $\{X_n\}$ being a sequence of iid r.v's with density $|x|^{-3}$ outside $(-1,1)$, the following is true:
$$
\frac{X_1+X_2 + \dots +X_n}{\sqrt{n\log n}} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}N(0,1).
$$

My idea is to use the taylor expansion of the characteristic function. But no matter what I do, I run into trouble with infinity and I cannot prove the convergence of the limit of c.f.

Can anybody give a hint? Thanks so much!

Comment: Later posted on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376848/proof-of-convergence-in-distribution-with-unbounded-moment).

Answer (score 0):

This question  was asked an other time [on Crosss Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376848/proof-of-convergence-in-distribution-with-unbounded-moment). One of the ideas of proof is to use Lindeberg central limit theorem to the array of random variables 
$$
Y_{n,k}:=X_k\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert X_k\right\rvert\leqslant n\right\} 
$$
and show that the contribution of the partial sums of $X_k\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert X_k\right\rvert\gt n\right\} $ is negligible.